# htaccss and urlencoded variable

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode

Here is an example of an URL as it gets passed when i click the button on the site.

http://www.site.com/account/messages/compose/316/&sbj=Web+Programmer+%2F+Developer&event=836

This is what i have for the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^account/messages/compose/([0-9]+)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?m=account_messages&p=compose&id=$1&sbj=$2&event=$3 [L]
```

id and event are always numbers, but subj can is an url encoded string
as it is right now its not working

Comment: Not working: what is it doing? what should it be doing? what else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Is your URL missing the `?` i.e. should it be http://www.site.com/account/messages/compose/316/?sbj=Web+Programmer+%2F+Developer&event=836

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

Since the `sbj` and `event` are already in the query string, the `QSA` flag will automatically pass them through i.e. it will rewrite

> http://www.site.com/account/messages/compose/316/?sbj=Web+Programmer+%2F+Developer&event=836

to the equivalent of

> http://www.site.com/index.php?m=account_messages&p=compose&id=316&sbj=Web+Programmer+%2‌​F+Developer&event=836

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^account/messages/compose/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?m=account_messages&p=compose&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Nope not working
Here is how my url looks with my seo urls turned OFF

   www.site.com/index.php?m=account_messages&p=compose&id=316&sbj=Web+Programmer+%2F+Developer&event=836

Comment: @misulicus What URL did you test with and what was the result? Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess, and is this rule the first one?

Comment: I have lots of other rules in htaccess..its a php script
I just need to add a rule for this specific part of the script.
WHere its sending an aditional 2 parameters, the $2 and $3

Comment: @misulicus What URL did you test with and what was the result?